# How to define routes types in React Navigation stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I need to define route types in the stack (not in the component), I know you can do it with RouteProp in components itself but I just couldn't figure it out how to apply that on a stack.

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="MarketAssetDetailsPage"
    options={({ route }) =>
      HeaderWithBackTitle({
        title: `${route.params.routeName} Market Details`,
        bgColor: route.params.data.assetColor,
        textColor: 'white',
      })
    }
    component={MarketAssetDetailsPage}
  />
```

Here I have a screen receiving routeName and a data. Eslint and typescript complains here, how to define types here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a type for the props.

```
export type StackParamList = {
  MarketAssetDetailsPage: {
    routeName: string,
    data: any // Change to be the type of data.
  }
}
```

Inside of your component you can do something like this

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type NavigationProps = StackNavigationProp<StackParamList, 'MarketAssetDetailsPage'>;

interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationProps
}

const MarketAssetDetailsPage = ({ navigation }: Props) => {

}
```

There is a good guide on the React Navigation website for TypeScript support - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/

Comment: so if I define on the component, can I see it on the stack as well ? Because that's where the problem is